# Checking multiple columns for multiple value mySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with columns say:

```
col1, col2, col3
```

I want to find if either values say 22 or 33 or 3 is/are in the columns.
For single value assume 22, I could have done:

```
SELECT * from table_name
WHERE 22 IN (col1, col2, col3)
```

How can I find 22, 33 in columns `col1, col2, col3`.

Any help is highly appreciable. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from table_name
WHERE col1 IN (1,2,3) or
      col2 IN (1,2,3) or
      col3 IN (1,2,3)
```

Maybe also like this

```
with search as
(
  select 1 v
  union all
  select 2 v
  union all
  select 3 v
)
select distinct t.* 
from table_name t
join search s on t.col1 = s.v or t.col2 = s.v or t.col3 = s.v
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=395ffd3c934a5421decef63f1803e3ab)

Comment: `with ... as (..)` won't work on MySQL unless the topicstarter is using MySQL 8.0 + which is unlikly because MySQL 8.0+ isn't production ready.

Comment: @RaymondNijland it is easy to rewrite into a query without `with`

Comment: i know  `join ( select 1 v union all ...)` would do the same.. but not all poeple know this.